# C++ - How to write a map to a file and read it back later

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a map of type

```
map<int,set<int> >
```

that I need to write to a file in the local disk and read it back later. It is too big to be stored in the program memory when the actual program is running. So I'm thinking of writing the contents of the map into a file instead and reading that back later. I know this can be done by using

```
FileOutputStream, ObjectInputStream and InputObjectStream
```

in Java. Is there a similar method possible in C++? I'm thiking of trying this with boost.

```
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
int main(){
    map<int,set<int> > mp;
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");
    boost::serialization::map M(ofs);
    M<<mp;
    //after this add key-value pairs to mp
}
```

Comment: http://www.stev.org/post/2012/03/19/C++-Read-Write-stdmap-to-a-file.aspx

I think this link may be usefull

Comment: There are many serialization libraries available for C++ ... for example boost::serialization

Comment: I want to write the map directly to a file. Not write it in the program memory at runtime and then write to a file at the end of the program. Would the boost libraries allow this?

Comment: @samurdhilbk have you looked it boost libraries' documentation?

Comment: I think the down vote is a bit unfair. Moving from Java to C++ can be overwhelming.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I updated the question after looking at the documentation.

Comment: So you can now answer your own question.

Comment: @steiner I'm not sure whether it is correct. Should try first.

Comment: Then I suggest you give it a try and edit back your issues, if any.

Comment: use rapidjson library

Comment: You say the map is too large for memory, are you basically asking if there is a C++ map that uses disk-backing rather than memory-backing?

Comment: @kfsone Even such a method is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many ways to serialize data with various tradeoffs.

The C++ standard library usually includes attempts at optimal solutions to problems; in cases where there is no optimal solution to be found, instead of picking one it just leaves it up to you, the end user.

It provides ways to write bytes to files.  It provides formatted streaming operations for console io of primitive types and `std::string`s and similar.

It does not include code to serialize the rest of the `std` containers.  There is no clear "best" answer.

There are many, many libraries that will provide serialization with various choices, interfaces and options attached, and various tradeoffs.  You can also write it yourself.

If you do write it yourself, be aware of endianness issues, and provide for seamless versioning with automatic fallback.  Also, provide a customization point for the contents of your container to be serialized, possibly recursively, possibly using different choices.  Ideally, you also want to have your serialization and deserialization code to be the *same code* being used in different ways (maybe with a different template parameter), and for it to be error-resistant (because once files are on disk, you cannot fix bugs in them).